# How to configure Reactor for distributed services?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, reactor, project-reactor

I have numerous services distributed on a private network and there is a service which has to broadcast a message to all other services(e.g. the expiration of authentication token). My application is based on java Spring framework and ever since I have started to get acquainted with an architecture that satisfy my condition, I found that it is called Event Driven Architecture and two famous frameworks related to this architecture are AKKA and Reactor. But reading the reactor tutorial (which integrates with spring much better than AKKA) I found that all services including Producer, And Consumer must submit into a Reactor class within the same context. Now I wonder if there is a way of distributing the services on multiple machines.

Comment: You have started to get 'antiquated'? Do you mean 'acquainted'?

Comment: whatever man, I'm rather eager to know the answer of the question, not misuse of spellchecker.

Comment: I cant say I know anything about AKKA or Reactor, but this sounds like an MQ thing.  You could set up ActiveMQ, and have all your distributed services subscribe to some topic.  When a message is pushed onto the MQ, your consumers would pick it up and do something with it.  Apache Camel has great support for this.

Comment: Hi!
Have you been abe to configure Reactor for distributed services?
I am dealing with te same problem now. :)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @AndreaT not yet :-(